# Node Axios Create Global Token Variable for Use in Separate Variable Header

Tags: node.js, axios

Using Node & Axios

**What I Want to Do**

In my `server.js` file, I want to call an api for a token that always changes, use axios (or other solution) to create a global token variable, and provide the global token to an app.get request header within an object, again, all within my server.js file.

**What I'm Trying**

I get the data using...

```
var data = '<tsRequest>\r\n\t<credentials name="name" password="pword">\r\n\t\t<site contentUrl="" />\r\n\t</credentials>\r\n</tsRequest>';

var config = {
  method: 'post',
  url: 'https://url.uni.edu/api/3.13/auth/signin',
  headers: { 
    'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
  },
  data : data
};
```

I try to create the global token variable (this is where I'm struggling)...

```
const token= axios(config)
.then((response) => {
  console.log(response.data.credentials.token);
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log(err);
});

console.log(token)
```

I have a functioning app.get request where instead of manually providing the token, I want to use the **const token**...

```
app.get('/gql', async (req, res) => {
    var someObject = {
      'method': 'POST',
      'url': 'https://diffurl.uni.edu/api/metadata/graphql',
      'headers': {
        'X-Some-Auth': token,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
```

**The Current Results**

What I have for the **var data =** and the **var config =** and the **axios(config)** all work to return the token via console.log, but I have 2 issues using axios.

**The Axios Issues**

1. In my hopes of creating a global token variable, I only understand how to get a **console.log** result instead of returning a 'useful data object'.
   In just about every piece of documentation or help found, the example uses console.log, which is not a practical example for learners to move beyond just returning the data in their console.
   What do I need to provide in axios to create a global token object in addition to or instead of console.log?
2. I realize 1. is my current blocker, but if I run my app, I get the following:

```
Promise { <pending> }
Express server running on port 1234
abc123 [the console.logged token via axios]
```

I'm not sure what the `Promise { <pending> }` means, how do I fix that?

**Beyond The Axios Issues**

If the axios problem is fixed, am I passing the `const token` correctly into my `app.get... var someObject... headers`?

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: _"token that always changes"_... as in per request? How often do you need to renew the token?

Comment: great question @Phil, I'm not exactly sure, it changes each time I call but I think it's good for 8 hours

Comment: That complicates matters somewhat. Does the `signin` API respond with any information about the expiry? What happens if you use an expired token? Do you get a particular response status back, eg `401`?

Comment: It doesn't look like I receive any expiry info, if I use an expired token posting to the api in postman, this is the returned body... ```{
    "timestamp": "2022-10-28T00:58:53.496+00:00",
    "status": 401,
    "error": "Unauthorized",
    "path": "/relationship-service-war"
}```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what [Axios interceptors](https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors) are for.

You can create an Axios instance with an interceptor that waits for the token request to complete before adding the token to the outgoing request.

A response interceptor can be added to handle 401 statuses and trigger a token renewal.

```js
const data = "<tsRequest>...</tsRequest>";

let renew = true;
let getTokenPromise;

const renewToken = () => {
  if (renew) {
    renew = false; // prevent multiple renewal requests
    getTokenPromise = axios
      .post("https://url.uni.edu/api/3.13/auth/signin", data, {
        headers: {
          "content-type": "text/plain", // are you sure it's not text/xml?
        },
      })
      .then((res) => res.data.credentials.token);
  }
  return getTokenPromise;
};

const client = axios.create();

// Request interceptor to add token
client.interceptors.request.use(async (config) => ({
  ...config,
  headers: {
    "X-Some-Auth": await renewToken(),
    ...config.headers,
  },
}));

// Response interceptor to handle expiry
client.interceptors.response.use(
  (res) => res,
  (error) => {
    if (error.response?.status === 401) {
      // Auth expired, renew and try again
      renew = true;
      return client(error.config);
    }
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);

// if putting this in a module...
// export default client;
```

The first time you try to make a request, the token will be retrieved. After that, it will continue to use the last value until it expires.

Comment: I think you're right re: text/xml... when I call the api in postman, the first line of the body returned is... ```<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>```

Comment: @Redink I just meant that your request body (`data`) looks like XML so the request `content-type` header should reflect that

Comment: Apologies, clarifying question... I updated my original to state that all of this takes place on my ```server.js``` file, but I see your solution begins with an ```// api/client.js``` file. Does this mean I'm running your solution/code on something other than my server file?

Comment: @Redink I just like to keep code modular but you don't have to. You'd just use `client` where you want to make requests, eg `client.get("https://example.com/")`

Comment: This is great Phil, thank you, follow-up question, after I've wined about console.log, which variable has the actual token data?
If I ```console.log(getTokenPromise);``` at the end of all code blocks = ```undefined```, if I try to console.log any other variables (like client or renewToken (which I get is a func)) no token is returned. What variable now holds the token that I would place in my app.get block?
```app.get('/gql', async (req, res) => {
    var someObj = {
      'method': 'POST',
      'url': '//diffurl...',
      'headers': {
        'X-Some-Auth': ***token***
      },```

Comment: That's the thing, you don't need it in your `app.get` or anywhere else. The interceptor will add the token for you. You just need to use `client.post('//diffurl', someDataYouWantToPost)`

Answer (score 1):

if you want to create a to send the token with every request in axios you should create a [custom axios instance](https://axios-http.com/docs/instance) or change the global axios default
you will find the way to do it [here](https://axios-http.com/docs/config_defaults), about promise problem you need to resolve it using .then

this how i think you should do it

```
// first create axios instance
// you can set config defaults while creating by passing config object see the docs
const instance = axios.create();
// then get the token from API
axios(config).then(response=>{
instance.defaults.headers.common["header you want to set"]=response.data.credentials.token
});
// then use the instance to make any request you want that should have the token
```

Comment: Just be careful, there could be timing issues with this where the `instance` is used before the token request has completed